# In jQuery Mobile how to remove the close icon in popup dialog

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

Does anyone know how to remove the close icon in the popup dialog.

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/dialog/index.html#&ui-state=dialog

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After looking at the structure of the dialog it is easy to understand that the below CSS can be used to hide the `Close` button.

```
.ui-header > .ui-btn { display: none; }
```

Note this will hide all the `.ui-btn` in `ui-header`. If that is not desired, you can write a simple script to make sure that we are just hiding the `Close` button alone.

For all dialogs in the page:

```
$(function () {
    $('.ui-btn', '.ui-header').filter (function () {
        return $.trim($(this).find('span.ui-btn-text').text()) == 'Close'; 
    }).hide();
});
```

For any specific dialog with ID `pageId`:

```
$(function () {
    $('.ui-header .ui-btn', '#pageId').filter (function () {
        return $.trim($(this).find('span.ui-btn-text').text()) == 'Close'; 
    }).hide();
});
```

See below for more details about the dialog structure.

Below is the the `X` (close icon) as in the beginning of the `div`, (See complete structure)

```
<a href="#" class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-btn-up-d ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-icon-notext" title="Close">
  <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
     <span class="ui-btn-text">Close</span>
     <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-delete ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span>
   </span>
 </a>
```

**Complete Structure** [cleaned up data attributes for readability]

```
<div role="dialog" class="ui-dialog-contain ui-corner-all ui-overlay-shadow">
  <div class="ui-corner-top ui-header ui-bar-d" role="banner">
    <a href="#" class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-btn-up-d ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-icon-notext" title="Close">
        <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
          <span class="ui-btn-text">Close</span>
          <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-delete ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span>
        </span>
     </a>
     <h1 class="ui-title" role="heading" aria-level="1">Dialog</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-corner-bottom ui-content ui-body-c" role="main">
    Dialog content
    <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-up-b">
      <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
        <span class="ui-btn-text">Sounds good</span>
      </span>
    </a>       
    <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-up-c">
       <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
         <span class="ui-btn-text">Cancel</span>
       </span>
     </a>    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: my comment somehow disappeared, so I will repeat it again: **great answer!** And the formerly 2 `Raja Ovi`s now merged into only one `Karthi Keyan`, that's ok for me, I do not have to understand that...

Answer (score 2):

The HTML is as follows.

```
<a href="#" class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-btn-up-d ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-icon-notext" title="Close">
  <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
     <span class="ui-btn-text">Close</span>
     <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-delete ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span>
  </span>
</a>
```

And all you have to do is

```
$(".ui-btn[title='close']").remove();
```

or

```
$(".ui-btn[title='close']").hide();
```

or

```
$(".ui-btn[title='close']").css('display', 'none');
```

or

```
$(".ui-btn[title='close']").attr("hidden", "hidden");
```

Answer (score 1):

Call the following after your dialog has loaded:

```
$(".ui-dialog a[data-icon='delete']").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just don't include an `<h1>` header on the page, or a div with `data-role="header"`

Comment: OP might still want a header, just not a close button

Answer (score 1):

HTML CODE:

```
 <div data-role="dialog" id="pageId">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="c" class="ui-header">
      <h2>your Heading</h2>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>Your Message.</p>
     </div>
 </div>
```

CSS CODE:

```
   #pageId div .ui-header a { display:none;}
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML CODE:

```
 <div data-role="dialog" id="pageId">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="c" class="ui-header">
      <h2>your Heading</h2>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>Your Message.</p>
     </div>
 </div>
```

CSS CODE:

```
   #pageId div .ui-header a { display:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your comment I think you want something like this:

```js
var dialog = ...
$("a[data-icon='delete']", dialog).css("display", "none"); // Hide it
// or
$("a[data-icon='delete']", dialog).remove(); // Remove it
```

`remove()`-ing might cause trouble with modules that expect the icon to be in that spot in the DOM. So I suggest the hiding variant.

If I guessed wrong and you want to remove all Xs from all dialogs, use Curt's selector, though I still suggest only hiding them. (It doesn't really hurt)

(Sorry Curt, I know it's close to your answer, but it was too long for a sensible comment.)

Answer (score 0):

Use popup dialog if you don't need close button
http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/popup/index.html#&ui-state=dialog

Comment: there is no icon in the example, try harder